# Ação ao clicar no limpar campo do vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Em um filtro onde os campos são preenchidos existe a necessidade as vezes de limpar o campo.

Estou tentando limpar um campo e reconhecer o valor daquela ação ao clicar no "x" para limpar o formulário

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que nada acontece.

Como estou fazendo?

```
<v-menu ref="menu" v-model="menu" :close-on-content-click="false" transition="scale-transition" offset-y max-width="290px" min-width="auto" >
   <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
       <v-text-field ref="mes" v-model="descMes" label="Mês" append-icon="mdi-calendar" v-bind="attrs"v-on="on" clearable autofocus dense outlined @click.clear="clear('mes')" />
   </template>
   <v-date-picker v-model="mes" no-title @input="menu = false" type="month" @click:month="parametroCliente" locale="pt-BR" />
</v-menu>
```

Ou seja, coloquei o atributo `@click.clear="clear('mes')"`

Onde existe uma função chamada `clear(param)` nos métodos

Mas isso só funciona se eu clicar dentro do campo, se eu clicar no 'x' do para acionar o `clearable` o campo é limpo porém a função não é acionada

Tentei também utilizando o @blur para que sair do campo identificar se o mesmo está vazio

Tudo isso é para um filtro que eu gostaria de fazer, onde se não tiver valor, é para buscar todos os meses

Existe alguma forma de acionar alguma ação ao clicar na opção 'X'?

Comment: cara aqui funciona mas eu utilizo o click no 'X' assim :  @click:clear="clear('mes')" testa ai ve se é a sintaxe mesmo

Comment: Isso mesmo, oh!

Comment: Vou responder a pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na sintaxe `@click.clear="clear('mes')"` troque para `@click:clear="clear('mes')"` não se exatamente porque mas acredito que o `:` adicione a um watcher no clique que mesmo quando você está fora do campo ele fica "escutando" o clique no botão de 'X'

Answer (score 3):

'click:clear' é o nome do evento disparado pelo elemento 'X', e não 'click.clear', então quando você cria um handler para o evento assim: `@click.clear="clear('mes')"`, você na verdade está colocando um listener em um evento que não existe.

Fazendo a troca para `@click:clear="clear('mes')"` conforme a solução do Germano Buss Niehues resolverá o problema!